# Data Validation using VBA with IF conditions not working

Tags: excel, vba, validation, formula

I'm trying to use Data Validation with an IF condition which can offer two different Data Validation lists. dvEntry and dvExit is a defined range (column of a table).

If I enter a formula in the Excdel cell it works fine:
=IF(AI6="ENTRY", dvEntry, IF(AI6="EXIT", dvExit, ""))

However, If I try to use two IF conditions like above in the VBA code, I get an error. ActiveRow is my currently selected row. TRIGGERcol is the Column for the data validation.

```
Set Reset = tbl.ListRows(ActiveRow)

    With Reset
       .Range(TRIGGERcol).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=IF(AI6=""ENTRY"", dvEntry, IF(AI6=""EXIT"", dvExit, """"))"
    End With
```

If I disable the second IF condition, it works. But then I can't use the feature needed. I've tried using IFS instead of IF with the same outcome. What is wrong with the VBA Validation when using multiple IF conditions?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="= IF( $AI$6 = ""ENTRY"", dvEntry, IF( $AI$6 = ""EXIT"", dvExit, TEXT(,) ) )"
End With
```

Replace `Selection` with the appropriated range.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Same issue, if I remove the second IF condition, it works, but not with both. I've double-checked my Validation Data and even set the second validation data to the first as well to make sure there are no issues with my validation. I tried even basic validation and it is extremely strange. For example: =IF(1=1, dvEntry, IF(2=1, dvExit, """")  this fails. However, =IF(1=1, IF(2=1, dvEntry, DvExit), """")    this works. I'm totally lost why such a basic function doesn't work. Any inputs greatly appreciated.

Comment: Estrange enough I tested it before posting the answer and it worked. Are you using the code as provided, as the example you mentioned "=IF(1=1, dvEntry, IF(2=1, dvExit, """")" it will not work because it's missing a parenthesis at the end, please ensure and confirm you are using the code as provided.